# Execute regexp_* functions on Oracle XE 11g

Tags: regex, replace, oracle-xe

After installing Oracle XE 11g on Windows Vista I am unable to exeute any of the regex functions that come with Oracle. (regexp_replace, regexp_instr etc)

The documentation on features @

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm

suggests regular expressions are supported.

As system I've viewed all_objects and I cannot see this package.

Does anyone know if there is an additional package install I need to apply ?

Comment: "*I am unable to exeute any of the regex functions*" is not a valid Oracle error message

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name correct because its not available to execute to give me an ORA- error message

Comment: If you use an unknown function you ***will*** get an ORA- message. What is the statement you are trying to run? And how (using which SQL client) are you running it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right. I was relying on an IDE with autocomplete(mistake 1) and then went to dba_objects to see if the function existed . It seems to be a built in without being listed in dba_objects . Sorry for wasting your time. It of course is working for me when I actually execute the query. thank you.